# How to use ng model for validation

Tags: angularjs

Well i m totally a newbie in AngularJS. I m trying to figure out how ng-model works.
What i m trying to do is get the string of the input field and see if it is equal to an other string. I checked the doc but couldn't figure out. Any advice to a beginner would be appreciated !

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('MainController',function($scope){
    if($scope.name === "Lisa"){
        alert("my name is lisa !");
    }
})
```

Comment: What is exactly your question ? What is not working in your current code ? Show us the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do the validation in the controller like in the example you need to set up a watcher on the model like this.

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller('MainController',function($scope){

    $scope.$watch('name', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        // NOTE: triggered on every change in $scope.name model
        if(newValue === "Lisa"){
            alert("my name is lisa !");
        }
    });
});
```

For more advanced validations you will need to create a directive that will require [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) directive and use its controller [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) to add custom validators.

Comment: No problem, I am glad I was able to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Copy pasted from the  Angular Docs :*

**ngModel**
- directive in module ng
The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

**ngModel is responsible for:**

Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as input, textarea or select require.

Providing validation behavior (i.e. required, number, email, url).
Keeping the state of the control (valid/invalid, dirty/pristine, touched/untouched, validation errors).

Setting related css classes on the element (ng-valid, ng-invalid, ng-dirty, ng-pristine, ng-touched, ng-untouched, ng-empty, ng-not-empty) including animations.

Registering the control with its parent form.

Note: ngModel will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the expression on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel